# Codeigniter reset auto increment on filled table issue

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am confused. I have tried to execute reset ai code in sql and IT WORKS.

```
SET @num := 0; UPDATE rancangan_bulanan SET id = @num := (@num+1);
```

But when I do it in CI:

```
// Location: rb_model.php
function reset_ai() {
    $sql = "SET  @num := 0; UPDATE rancangan_bulanan SET id = @num := (@num+1);";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

it gave me an error.

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE rancangan_bulanan SET id = @num := (@num+1)' at line 1

SET @num := 0; UPDATE rancangan_bulanan SET id = @num := (@num+1);

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/belajar/rkape/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Any advise?

Comment: What is your PHP code?

Comment: @Antony I've edited my question